# Can I use Spartacus Banner Component only without Storefront?

Tags: javascript, angular, spartacus-storefront

I want to build an application, but wanted to use a few components of the Spartacus. For example, My application will have the following component:

> My own created Header
>
> **Spartacus Banner**
>
> My own created Footer

The data in the Banner component will come from my own API, not from the SAP Commerce cloud.
I know that it seems odd, but it is the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use some certain Spartacus components without using Storefront module, cuz almost each Angular component inside Spartacus library is representation of the same CMS Component and the part of the monolith Spartacus Storefront application. Almost each Spartacus component depends on core mechanisms of getting data from SAP Commerce Cloud.

On the other hand, if you really want to use only several Spartacus components, it's make no sense in using Spartacus at all, the simplest way will be in implementing your own Angular components, which will be similar to Spartacus.